# How to add ElementHost to Datagridview Cells in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, datagridview, elementhost

I want to add ElementHost  to my datagridview to bring the designed WPF control to the win form. 
My question is how to do this! This is my code so far:

```
            dgv.Columns[0].Name = "controls?";
            ElementHost host = new ElementHost();
            UserControl1 uc;
            uc = new UserControl1(10,20);
            host.Name = "test";
            host.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            host.Child = uc;
            dgv.Columns.Add(host); //< this gives me error!
```

I tried both `dgv.Columns.Add(host)` and `dgv.Controls.Add(host)` but they are not working.
Is there anyway to do this?
Thanks for the help.

p.s. datagridview should have 10 rows and each row has one usercontrol embedded in each cell.

Comment: Did you found any way to do this? I have the same question..

Comment: Not yet:( I changed my strategy entirely to get around this problem